# Classify the finite-dimensional indecomposable representations of the quiver $A_n$

Tags: representation-theory, quiver, representation-of-algebras

I have to classify the finite-dimensional indecomposable representations of the quiver $A_n$ up to isomorphism:

1 $\longrightarrow$ 2 $\longrightarrow \cdots
\longrightarrow$ n

Any idea of how to approach this??

Answer (score 1):

There is a general theory which implies that the indecomposable representations of a quiver that arises as an orientation of a simply-laced Dynkin diagram of finite type are in bijection with the positive roots of the corresponding root system, in such a way that the dimension vector of an indecomposable representation is given by the coefficients of the corresponding positive root on the simple roots. This result is due to Gabriel, with a later important refinement of Bernstein, Gelfand, and Ponomarev. The main tool in this general approach is the set of *reflection functors* defined by BGP.

However, in your case the algebra of the quiver is simply the algebra of $n$ by $n$ upper triangular matrices, and you may approach the problem via that identification.